# Location and GeoPoint distanceTo()

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, geopoints

I have location of user(class Location). And list of GeoPoints. Is it some function to calculate distance? Or write own function it is the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way would be to use the distanceBetween function in the Android Location class.

```
Location userLocation = new Location();
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint();
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude(), (geoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1E6), (geoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1E6), results); 
//result[0] = distance in m
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple math equation. See [Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Distance_in_Euclidean_space)

Ensure that your units make sense. If there is not a library function to perform this, the coding is completely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

[Openmap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) is a library to build applications with maps. It has classes and methods for distance and azimuth calculation between two points. See class [Geo](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/geo/Geo.html).

If the library is too big, you can download sources from svn and copy only the class Geo and its dependencies.